# How to pattern match on Scala Scopt optional arguments

Tags: scala, optionparser, scopt

I have a simple Scops parser that looks like

```
val parser: scopt.OptionParser[Config] = new scopt.OptionParser[Config]("my-app") {
  head("scopt", "3.x")
  (...)

  opt[String]('q', "query")
    .text("The query.")
    .action { (value, conf) => conf.copy(
      query = value
    )}
    .optional
}
(...)
parser.parse(args, Config()) match {
  case Some(config) => drive(config)
(...)
```

In my driver function I want to initialize a parameter with what the user provided via the argument or some default value otherwise.

I could do something like

```
var myQuery = _
if config.query != "" myQuery = config.query
else myQuery = config.query
```

But, (i) I doubt that testing against the empty string is the right way to check if the user provided an optional argument or not and (ii) that doesn't look like a very functional to write this in Scala.

Question: Is there a nice functional way to do this? I considered pattern matching like below but the Scopt arguments do not seem to be returned as Option[String]

```
val myQuery: String = config.query match {
  case Some(q) => q
  case None => "This is the default query"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make `Config#query` an `Option[String]` (with `None` as default) and change the `query = value` line to `query = Some(value)`.

Comment: Thanks Alexey. I thought that there was a way to define Option values through Scopt API for the... optional arguments ;) The solution you uploaded works as well.